# Main menubar does not show up Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, menu, tkinter

i have problem... my main menubar, which was created by tkinter, does not show up. It's very strange situation, because when i put submenu to window.config(menu=filemenu) [for example], it works fine, but it shows up horizontally (i think like mainmenu should do).

```
window = tkinter.Tk()
window.title("SAPC - Scanned Aerial Photographs Correction")
window.geometry("300x300+300+300")  
window.iconbitmap(default='favicon.ico') 
logo1=PIL.Image.open("logo.png")
logo2 = PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage(logo1)
tkinter.Label(window, text="Ver.1.0 Beta")
tkinter.Label(window,image=logo2).grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2, rowspan=2, sticky=tkinter.N+tkinter.E+tkinter.S+tkinter.W) 

menubar=tkinter.Menu(window)
filemenu = tkinter.Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
filemenu.add_command(label="Open", command=window.quit)
filemenu.add_command(label="Close", command=window.quit)

editmenu = tkinter.Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
editmenu.add_command(label="Undo", command=window.quit)
window.config(menu=menubar)
window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating an empty menubar. If you want your file and edit menus to appear, you must add them to the menubar:

```
menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=filemenu)
menubar.add_cascade(label="Edit", menu=editmenu)
```